# "The volumes of tubes in a Riemannian manifold" by Alfred Gray

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I am looking for a specific paper by Gray/Vanhecke with the title

"The volumes of tubes in a Riemannian manifold"

published in 1981. Note that there is another paper with the title "The volumes of tubes **about curves** in a Riemannian manifold" which was published in 1982, and that this is not the paper I am looking for for. So far I did not find any way of accessing this paper, be it free or behind a paywall. Any source for access to this paper would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this list of publications, it says it was published in Rendiconti del Seminario Matematico Universitá e Politecnico Torino.

https://web.archive.org/web/20050213080244/http://www.ehu.es/gray/publications.html

> The volumes of tubes in a Riemannian manifold, Rendiconti del
>   Seminario Matematico Universitá e Politecnico Torino 39 no. 3 (1981),
>   1--50. (with L. Vanhecke).

In the site of the Seminario, you can ask them for the reference, or at least it's what they say.

http://www.seminariomatematico.unito.it/rendiconti/cartaceo/39-3.html

Also, there's this book in his honour«Global Differential Geometry:
The Mathematical Legacy
·of Alfred Gray ». It might be useful.

And good luck in your search and study.

Comment: @Hirshy. If you ask them, they'll surely send yo a copy: last year I asked for a copy of a paper of Francesco Tricomi which was published in the "Seminario" in 1949, and they sent me a copy within two weeks.

Comment: Thank you very much, I contacted the "Seminario" and will (have to) wait now for their response!